# JAVA RMI Addition example

Tags: java, rmi

I m Implementing a simple Java RMI application. It's main objective is to add 2 integer. The code source is the following: 
**AdditionInterface for both client and server side**
`import java.rmi.*;
 public interface AdditionInterface extends Remote {
 public int add(int a,int b) throws RemoteException;
 }`

**Addition.java**

```
 import java.rmi.*;
 import java.rmi.server.*;

 public class Addition extends UnicastRemoteObject
 implements AdditionInterface {

 public Addition () throws RemoteException { }

 public int add(int a, int b) throws RemoteException {
 int result=a+b;
 return result;
 }
 }
```

**AdditionServer**

```
import java.rmi.*;
 import java.rmi.server.*;

 public class AdditionServer {
 public static void main (String[] argv) {
 try {
 System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());

 Addition Hello = new Addition();
 Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost/ABC", Hello);

 System.out.println("Addition Server is ready.");
 }catch (Exception e) {
 System.out.println("Addition Server failed: " + e);
 }
 }
}
```

**AdditionClient**

```
import java.rmi.*;

 public class AdditionClient {
 public static void main (String[] args) {
 AdditionInterface hello;
 try {
 System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
 hello = (AdditionInterface)Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost/ABC");
 int result=hello.add(9,10);
 System.out.println("Result is :"+result);

 }catch (Exception e) {
 System.out.println("HelloClient exception: " + e);
 }
 }
 }
```

**Security Policy for both client and server side**

```
    grant {
        permission java.security.AllPermission;

  };
```

However i get the HelloClient exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "127.0.0.1:1099" "connect,resolve")
 error

Comment: Get rid of the `SecurityManagers`. You don't need them unless you're using the codebase feature. which you aren't.

Answer (score -1):

You have to start the RMI registry first. Try to call

```
java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
```

before trying to (re)bind your remote object. I am not sure but this call may fail if the registry is already started.
Your second problem may be that the policy applied by your SecurityManager does not have permissions to connect/resolve localhost. Try ro comment out `System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());` to get started. The default java policy file has only one SocketPermission granted:

```
permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:0", "listen";
```

Comment: If this was the problem he would be getting a `BindException` or `ConnectExcepton`.

Comment: @user207421 You are right. Creating of the registry _might_ be the next problem to stumble upon but is not the cause of the mentioned exception.